# WebStorm auto change something in files

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I edit file with WebStorm, Git detect a lot of changes which I didn't make.

[image]

Sometimes whole file that I have edit, can be marked as changed.

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot clearly shows that the difference is in leading whitespace (indents) *on empty lines*.

You do not need indents on empty lines .. so IDE removes them on Save. If you do not want that, configure IDE accordingly:

`Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Strip trailing spaces on Save`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a problem that can arise when your editor is configured to auto-format code.

Auto-indentation to some given (often language-specific, but user-configurable) values, changing tabs to spaces, changing line endings (CRLF or LF), there are many ways an editor can mess with your opened files if you're not well aware of how it's set to operate.

I'd encourage you to investigate into the different options of the editor to disable each trouble-making feature on an individual basis. A few minutes spent, hours gained in git head-scratchings.